# Getting Exception "Application tried to present modally a view controller" in react native ios

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Below is my .main class. When I am running my app in device its getting exception , but its working in simulator . Please suggest. Thanks

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));// //here are exception what i can see in xcode
  }
}


expiation :Application tried to present modally a view controller

reason  __NSCFString *  "Application tried to present modally a view controller <UIViewController: 0x10785cb20> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x107e07440>."    0x000000028258c580
```

Comment: In iOS, you cannot present more than one controller above another controller. There is a single presented controller at a time.

Comment: @son - the how i can fix it , could you please help me

Comment: I have no experience with react-native. So I could explain the root cause. You must identify where the crash is and figure out if there are any operations that provide a controller, might be executed twice, or something like that. Ensure that only one controller is presented at any given time on the same view.

Answer (score 0):

- You're trying to present a view controller modally, but it's already being presented by another view controller. This is not allowed in iOS.

  ```
  import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
  import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

  const MyComponent = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
    const handleShowModal = async () => {
     try {
       await MyModalComponent.show();
     } catch (error) {
       if (error.message.includes('already being presented')) {
         await MyModalComponent.hide();
         await MyModalComponent.show();
       } else {
         throw error;
       }
     }
   };

   const handleHideModal = async () => {
     await MyModalComponent.hide();
   };

   const handleButtonPress = async () => {
     await handleHideModal();
     await handleShowModal();
   };

   return (
     <View>
       <Button title="Show Modal" onPress={handleButtonPress} />
     </View>
   );
  }, []);

  return null;
  };
  ```
- MyModalComponent is the view controller you're trying to present modally. The handleShowModal function attempts to show the modal.